# How to calculate the diffrence beween two dates in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, time, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I need to calculate the difference between two I18n time objects in weeks.

For example:

```
date1 = Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object(
[time] => 2020-04-21T12:00:00-00:00
[timezone] => America/Toronto
[fixedNowTime] =>)
```

and

```
date2 = Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object(
[time] => 2020-05-05T12:00:00-00:00
[timezone] => America/Toronto
[fixedNowTime] =>)
```

Expected output :

```
date2-date1 = 2.
```

Comment: Why would the expected result be `2`? The difference between the two dates is `1` year and `14` days.

Comment: `$date1->diffInDays($date2)` might be helpful?

Comment: @ndm, yes I am sorry. I meant to type 2020-04-21 in date1. I have edited date in question to 2020.

Comment: @GregSchmidt thanks a lot. That works.